# Specify table for Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm running into an issue with a foreign key constraint.

I have three models:

`PreferredDayTime` (join table between users and)

`DayTime` (a collection of daytimes - connecting a day of the week and time of day)

and `Day` (each day of the week).

When creating a `PreferredDayTime`, I get a foreign key constraint, that the specified `day_time_id` does not exist on the table `days`.

I think rails is looking for a `time_id` in the `days` table, instead of a `day_time_id` in the `day_times` table.

**How can I specify that the foreign key is not on the days table?**

Not sure what to google with respect to the overlapping names

Comment: You can specify the foreign key on the `belongs_to` method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include foreign key , write

```
belongs_to: PreferredDayTime
```

In your DateTime model class

Answer (score 1):

You can specify foreign key:

```
has_many :days, class_name: "Days", foreign_key: "any_desirable_key_id"
```